# Meaning of "longago" (as an adjective) in a context

Tags: meaning, ambiguity

I think there's a slight ambiguity in the word **longago** in this context.

> the **longago** Deputy Speaker who was killed in the National Assembly when the furniture was flung at him by elected representatives. <sub>Source: Salman Rushdie - [*Shame (1983)*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=EL4qJdBgj7oC&pg=PA69&dq=%22Deputy+Speaker+who+was+killed+in+the+National+Assembly%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjkuoiioNLiAhUCaBoKHXl9C5wQ6AEINjAC#v=onepage&q=%22Deputy%20Speaker%20who%20was%20killed%20in%20the%20National%20Assembly%22&f=false)</sub>

I can't figure out whether it means "the former Deputy speaker" or it means "Deputy speaker who died long time ago"

I found a word **long-ago** and its [explanation](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/long-ago) in Merriam-Webster, but I'm not sure it's the same word.

---

Some [background](https://wikivisually.com/wiki/Shahed_Ali_Patwary) on events Salman Rushdie is referring to:

> Shahed Ali Patwary was a lawyer and prominent politician. He was elected as member of East Pakistan Provincial Assembly. In 1955 he was elected as Deputy Speaker. On 23 September 1958 he was injured in a fight in the assembly and died two days later.

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen _long ago_ written as one word, but it clearly means that the incident happened a long time ago. If people threw things at him in the Assembly he was presumably in office at the time, and if he was killed he didn't live to be a 'former Deputy Speaker'!.

Comment: The full [Oxford English Dictionary](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/109984?rskey=RWdrl7&result=2#eid) lists hyphenated ***long-ago*** as a valid "attributive adjective" form, but it's relatively rare (maybe not so much in "Indian English", which Rushdie might have been deliberately leaning towards). Compare ***long-time, long-term***, both of which are still in common use.

Comment: @KateBunting - Clearly "long-ago" is modifying "Deputy Speaker", meaning that he is not Deputy Speaker now, nor was he in the near past.  Whether he was Deputy Speaker at the time of the incident is unclear, and would have to be derived from the wider context (and perhaps knowledge of the writer's style).

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Maybe it's my age, but I wouldn't consider "long-ago" to be particularly archaic or non-idiomatic.  In fact, Ngram shows it on the ascent in the last 50 years.

Comment: @HotLicks: Quite. It's even feasible the former Deputy Speaker was actually killed *recently* - all we know from the text is that it was a long time ago when he held that office, which doesn't necessarily tell us anything about when he died.

Comment: ...as regards the "currency" of Rushdie's usage, I'd have to say I'm not familiar with this ***leading position attributive adjective*** usage with ***long-ago***, regardless of the orthography. So ***That was our long-ago plan** [- we have a new one now]* just sounds weird to me, whereas ***This is our long-term plan*** and ***He's my [long-time friend**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22my+long-time+friend%22)* sound perfectly natural.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - To me it's just placing the adjective in it's most logical place, just ahead of the modified noun.  In your construction it's "weird" because saying "This was our plan long ago" is far more natural -- there's no need to use the adjective when modifying "to be" is clearer.  However, one might say "Our long-ago plan was to ...", since in that case  modifying the verb is less "logical".

Comment: I would consider 'longago' this a typo or error. Without context, I thought it was some back disease or Italian clown.

Comment: @HotLicks: According to [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+long-ago+time%2Ca+time+long+ago&year_start=1820&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20long%20-%20ago%20time%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20time%20long%20ago%3B%2Cc0), the hyphenated "leading attributive" form ***a long-ago time*** (as opposed to my preferred form ***a long time ago***) has gained significant traction in recent decades, particularly in AmE. Which I find strange, since it sounds "dated, literary" to me, rather than a snappy new form gaining traction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the longago Deputy Speaker who was killed in the National Assembly
>   when the furniture was flung at him by elected representatives.
>   Source: Salman Rushdie - Shame (1983)

As all the comments have said this is just another way of saying long-ago
and all it tells us was that the deputy speaker who had furniture thrown at him held his post a long time ago.

We do not know how long he held the post.
It is most likely he was in the post when the incident happened but we can not say that with 100% accuracy[1].
He may have been deputy at 30 and came to visit at 90 when the furniture got thrown.

We do not even know when this was **long-ago** is >50 years to me >10 years to my teenager.

---

[1] but if anyone wrote this text not intending you to understand he was the deputy at the time of the furniture incident, they are either bad writers, or writing a riddle. (who was the deputy when somebody got killed with furniture?)